# File mode specification error: (void-variable lsp-csharp--action-client-find-references)

Tags: lsp-mode, doom, haskell-mode, lsp, lsp-ui

I'm using doom emacs.

my `~/.doom.d/config.el` is -

```
(use-package! lsp-mode
:hook
(haskell-mode . lsp)
:commands
lsp)

(use-package! lsp-ui
:commands
lsp-ui-mode)

(use-package! lsp-haskell
:after haskell-mode
:config
(setq lsp-haskell-process-path-hie "ghcide")
(setq lsp-haskell-process-args-hie '())
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook #'lsp)
)


(use-package! haskell-mode
:mode "\\.hs$"
:config
(rainbow-delimiters-mode)
;; (setq haskell-font-lock-symbols t)
;;(add-to-list ("<>" . "⊕"))
(setq haskell-font-lock-symbols-alist
        (-reject
        (lambda (elem)
        (or))
        haskell-font-lock-symbols-alist)))
```

whenever i open haskell file i get error `File mode specification error: (void-variable lsp-csharp--action-client-find-references)` -

[image]

OS details -

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 32 (Thirty Two)
Release:        32
Codename:       ThirtyTwo
```

emacs details -

```
$ emacs -version
GNU Emacs 27.1
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reinstalling lsp-mode and eventually unpinning the lsp-mode package. If this does not help, can you post the error callstack after M-x toggle-debug-on-error?

Comment: what do you mean my unpinning lsp-mode?.

Comment: https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/742ff5629c5c26a4904cb8a7b3cdc3aebb9c951c/docs/getting_started.org#pinning-packages-to-specific-commits